# Django - Aggregate survey responses into string

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building out a survey in django.  I would like to store the responses of the survey into a single string rather than a bunch of individual variables.  My hope is that using this structure I can store surveys of varying lengths into a single table.  I'm not sure how you loop through the survey responses and aggregate them and insert them into the db using django's ORM model. I'm guessing that you have to use raw SQL?  Suggestions or URLs on where I might start appreciated.  A more concrete example below.

## Basic DB Design

PID=UUID
Responses=Char256

## Survey example

```
    <p>1.    Item 1.<p>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1">Very Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="2">Moderately Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="3">Neither Accurate or Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="4">Moderately Accurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="5">Very Accruate<br>

    <p>2.    Item 2.<p>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="1">Very Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="2">Moderately Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="3">Neither Accurate or Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="4">Moderately Accurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="5">Very Accruate<br>

    <p>3.    Item 3.<p>
    <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="1">Very Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="2">Moderately Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="3">Neither Accurate or Inaccurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="4">Moderately Accurate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="5">Very Accruate<br>
```

## Assume the following responses

Q1: '1'
Q2: '2'
Q3: '3'

How do I insert this into my DB model as '123' rather than having a model that requires me to enter '1' into a variable q1, '2' into a variable q2, and '3' into a variable q3, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get you in the right direction. Either create a Question model with a name and a charfield of options. Your form would be created using a ModelForm. That way Django does most of the work for you.

An alternative is to use an external package. [django-domande](https://github.com/bulkan/django-domande) seems like a good survey app.